# Evenly reducing an indexed array by 10%

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array filled with data over the period of a month. The data is computed for every 15 minutes over that period, meaning it's got about 2880 entries.

I need to reduce it by about 10% in order to display the data in a chart (288 data points will render much more nicely than 2880).

Here's what I've tried (it works, but it might be a very bad method):

```
$count = count($this->Data1Month);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 10) {
    $tempArray[] = $this->DataMonth[$i];
}
$this->Data1Month = $tempArray;
```

Comment: what kind of efficiency are you after?

Comment: I believe foreach is faster than for loop for arrays

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for a code review.

Comment: Unless you have reason to think that that code is somehow slowing down your program, I would go with whatever code most clearly shows the intent to future readers of the code.  The first rule of Optimization Club is Do Not Optimize.  The second rule of Optimization Club is Do Not Optimize Without Measuring.

Comment: @Mooseman It's not a code review. I added the code to give an example of "what I've already tried". I could remove it if you think it would improve my question...?

Comment: I don't see the problem with your current code. you should really explain what you wish to improve on it.

Comment: @eis If the current code doesn't have something glaringly wrong with it, that's fine. I wasn't sure if there was a PHP function or some other better way of doing this. In terms of how it could be improved: Speed only.

Comment: @Chuck "I wasn't sure if there was ... some other better way of doing this" Sounds pretty much like a Code Review to me.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm not so sure this is a good Code Review question. Code Review is about doing the same thing in a better way, this feels more like asking about a better *thing* to do, i.e. changing the behavior of the code. I think it is borderline for Code Review

Comment: Some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939581/selecting-every-nth-item-from-an-array

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg As far as I can see, the required behaviour is explicit in the title: "Evenly reducing an indexed array by 10%". An alternative implementation for that requirement with better performance, robustness, or readability is a code review suggestion. (Note that I'm not talking about codereview.stackexchange here, just the concept of reviewing fully working code to see if it can be improved, as distinct from examining non-working code to find the problem.)

Comment: @IMSoP I meant that there are different ways to reduce it, for example another implementation might be to use the *average* values for the first ten and put that as a value in the resulting array. This particular question, *might* be on-topic on Code Review, but I don't think it is *off-topic* on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Like I say, I wasn't making any judgement about where it should go instead, just that it didn't seem like it fitted here. I don't feel strongly about it, though, just justifying my vote.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the most efficient solution, but you do have a mistake though. Array indexes start at zero so 0+10 needs to be 9, like so:

```
$count = count($this->Data1Month);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 9) {
    $tempArray[] = $this->DataMonth[$i];
}
$this->Data1Month = $tempArray;
```

Comment: This would iterate 2880 times through the array. The current code only loops 288 times.

Comment: not to mention deletes original data, which might or might not be wanted

Comment: @Chuck I think you have the most efficient solution then, but you do have a mistake though. Array indexes start at zero so 0+10 needs to be 9. See my edit please. Speaking of which: my original solution did not take that into account either lol